# Ambiguous results for the same code- Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm fetching some models from database using Laravel Eloquent. The code is like this-

```
$jobs = User::find($request->user_id)
                ->jobs
                ->where('status', $request->status);
return $jobs;
```

For the value of `status = 0`, the output is an array of objects-

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Mwkkdndnnd",
        "desc": ".amsmsmskxnndsmsms",
        "credits": "100",
        "category_id": "1",
        "views": "0",
        "user_id": "11",
        "deadline": "2017-07-19",
        "status": "0",
        "assigned_to": null,
        "assigned_on": null,
        "closed_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-07-17 09:57:28",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-17 09:57:28"
    }
]
```

But for the value of `status = 1`, the output is an object containing multiple objects-

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Promote my company ",
        "desc": "My brand needs to be promoted.",
        "credits": "100",
        "category_id": "1",
        "views": "0",
        "user_id": "11",
        "deadline": "2017-07-20",
        "status": "1",
        "assigned_to": "12",
        "assigned_on": "2017-07-18 09:32:51",
        "closed_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-07-17 18:43:50",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-18 09:32:51"
    }
}
```

What is wrong the code?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The ->jobs line is surely the problem. Can you explain it? It's not clear if it's a table or something else.

Comment: I have defined a method jobs() on users table. It is a hasMany() relationship.

Comment: My mistake, no relation with ->jobs. Add a ->get() to finish the query and see the results.

Comment: It is giving an error- Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Comment: Right. The problem is that the find() method serves as a where clause, and after that you give the query another where clause. For some reason it worked but not without issues. Try changing the query to DB::table('user')->where(['ID','=','1'],['status','=','0'])->get().

Comment: The find() method is on users table, and then I'm fetching all the jobs belonging to that users from jobs table, where status of the job is 1. SO, i think, there should be no problem.

Comment: @Omisakin Oluwatobi agrees with me and gave a much better answer.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira same result again.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira your comment is very correct in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience with chaining another where with find, there can be unexpected behavior. So you should attempt to simply change everything to where, i.e,

```
$jobs = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->jobs->where('status', $request->status);
```

Because generally, the find method will return One model that matches, and calling a where on that model the key is not preserved so it just does a query on all the records instead of one. I may not be entirely correct, but I am pretty sure about find with where in this situation.

I would propose in order to actually see whats wrong, simply call the Job model directly and find where you have that user id (in case the relationship exists in this direction)

```
Job::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->get();
```

In fact, my observation is that you might be nursing a potential issue where if user with that id does not exist, then one uncaught error is triggered to the user. Do a check somehow in that place. `findOrFail()` might be helpful.

Comment: tried this $jobs = User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first()->jobs->where('status', $request->status);, still the same result..

Comment: no, dont put first before you add where. simply use the example I gave, in deed if that id in User is unique, you don't need the first. adding first before joining the relationship would almost mean the same thing you were doing with find (if I understood correctly) In my opinion, the second example is much clearer

Comment: In that way it's giving an error. And obviously, it will give an error because I have to fetch jobs of a single user not multiple, and where returns an array without first method, even if it has a single element.

Comment: The error is - "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$jobs"

Comment: And thanks for your second suggestion for directly calling Job model. It is working absolutely fine.